# Display a number in Mathematica 9 in periodic form

Tags: numerics, output-formatting, formatting

I want to display a rational number in *Mathematica* in periodic style.
`PeriodicForm` isn't working anymore. It worked in *Mathematica* 5 and now I'm using *Mathematica* 9.

I want to display the number $3.13678989898989898989\ldots$, where the repeating $89$ part should be displayed as $3.1367\overline{89}$

Comment: See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatingDecimal.html) is `RealDigits` the replacement for what you want?

Comment: i want to display the following number
3.13678989898989898989
and the 8989 part should be displayed as periodic

Comment: Your question implies that there is/used to be some kind of solution or function (`PeriodicForm`?) which does not work anymore, which is a bit puzzling.

Comment: http://books.google.at/books?id=dAoYMXurN5cC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=mathematica+periodische+zahl&source=bl&ots=D7U1LR0ghH&sig=rEOhZkbsIbe41AIhy39ko7njLxA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XMBvUsnkLIH27Aart4GACw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=mathematica%20periodische%20zahl&f=false

Comment: @YvesKlett Apparently it was a function in the `NumberTheory` package that was in versions 6 and earlier.

Comment: Did you try loading the package as described a page earlier (http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6773)?

Comment: Yes, but the function is now deprecated regarding to the documentation.

Answer (score 13):

You can always write your own version of `PeriodicForm`:

```
ClearAll@PeriodicForm
PeriodicForm[n_] := RealDigits[n] /. {{d___Integer, {i__Integer} ...}, l_Integer} :> 
    PeriodicForm[n, l, {d}, {i}]

Format[PeriodicForm[n_, l_, d_, i_]] ^:= Interpretation[Row[{
    FromDigits[d ~Take~ l] /. {} -> 0,
     ".", 
    Sequence @@ d ~Drop~ l, 
    OverBar[FromDigits@i]
}] /. OverBar[0] :> Sequence[], n]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice - I started down this route, then realized I was just procrastinating from all the grading I have to do.

Answer (score 8):

To get `PeriodicForm` working in Mathematica 9 (and probably other versions after 6) you need to first download the obsolete package from the [Wolfram Library Archive](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6773).  Run the package, ignore the errors and have fun:

```
Get["http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6773/\
   ContinuedFractions.m?file_id=6182"]
PeriodicForm[RealDigits[19/7]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could use URLSave to install package. URLSave["http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6773/ContinuedFractions.m?file_id=6182", 
 FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", 
   "ContinuedFractions.m"}]] and << ContinuedFractions`

Comment: I wonder why this package is not integrated into the kernel. I suspect there are some subtleties that it cannot yet handle. Btw, you may want to show the FullForm of your example.

Answer (score 5):

Or, without the package, you can use

```
RealDigits[19/7]
{{2, {7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5}}, 1}
```

which shows the repeated decimal portion in the second (list) element of the answer. This tells you that the answer is `2` followed by repeating `714285`. The final 1 is the exponent and allows the same representation to handle much larger or smaller numbers.

Comment: Yes, `RealDigits` is the place to start.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200617/how-can-i-make-a-working-repeating-decimal-representation-of-a-rational-number) you will find a discussion of issues related to the production of repeated decimals.

The code is reproduced below for convenience.

```
repeatingDecimal[n_Integer | n_Real] := n

Format[repeatingDecimal[q_Rational]] := 
Row@Flatten[{IntegerPart@q, ".", RealDigits@FractionalPart@q} /. {{nr___Integer, r_List: {}}, 
  pt_} :> {Table[0, {-pt}], nr, OverBar /@ r}]

repeatingDecimal[q_] + x_ ^:= q + x
repeatingDecimal[q_]*x_ ^:= q*x
repeatingDecimal[q_]^x_ ^:= q^x
```

**Examples**

```
n1 = 1; n2 = 15; ClearAll[i, k, r];
TableForm[Table[repeatingDecimal[i/j], {i, n1, n2}, {j, n1, n2}], 
TableHeadings -> {None, Table[("r")/k, {k, n1, n2}]}]
```

[image: table]

---

Simple arithmetic operations such as addition can be carried out on the repeating decimals.

```
a = repeatingDecimal[7/31];
b = repeatingDecimal[24/31];
Print["a = ", a]
Print["b = ", b]
Print["a + b = ", a, " + ", b, " = ", a + b]
```

[image: notation]