# Displaying the repeating decimal expansion of a rational number

Tags: numerics, output-formatting, number-representation

How do I write a decimal expansion of a rational number $a/b$ with only periodic part, e.g., given $1/7=0.14285714285714285714 \ldots$, I want just $0.142857$, the periodic part of $1/7$, to be displayed. I think I was able to do it sometime ago (with `RealDigit` or something similar), but now I forget what I did.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html):

> For integers and rational numbers with terminating digit expansions, `RealDigits[x]` returns an ordinary list of digits. For rational numbers with non‐terminating digit expansions, it yields a list of the form `{a1,a2,…,{b1,b2,…}}` representing the digit sequence consisting of the `ai` followed by infinite cyclic repetitions of the `bi`.»

```
Print@RealDigits[1/7]
(* {{{1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7}}, 0} *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxCEoNTHHJTM9s6Q42lDfPPb/fwA)

If you instead want to display real numbers in periodic form (with an overbar), use [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35019/61597).